# Why do my roses look dry, brown and full of holes?

Tags: diseases, roses, pest-damage

I've been using Bayer's BioAdvance Rose and Flower care to feed and prevent insects/diseases. It did ok last season, not wonderful, but ok. This season my rose bushes are dry, they have brown/rust spots and holes all over.

I'm carefully and faithfully following Bayer's directions. How can I save my roses? I'm afraid they'll die.

[image]
[image]

https://ibb.co/album/Z6cKcb
Thank you.

P.S., these rose bushes are located in USDA region 6b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is Diplocarpon rosae fungus ( Rose Black Spot). The fungus is plant specific to Roses, so it is unlikely to infect other plants.

I don't think that I have ever used Bayer's BioAdvance Rose and Flower, however I don't like garden products that are 'all in one' types. I have found that products that claim to do more than one thing, such as fertilize and prevent disease, don't do either of those things very well and often contain chemicals you don't really need. These products can also seriously over fertilize your garden. If you apply too much chemical fertilizer all at once, even in outside, in ground gardens, the fertilizer can still cause 'fertilizer burn' to plant roots.

An 'all in one' product seems more convenient, but it isn't in the long run. It is best to get separate products (fertilizer, fungicide, insecticide) tailored to the specific needs of your garden and plants.

To control the Rose Black Spot on your roses, you are going to need a good commercial fungicide. When I absolutely need to use a commercial fungicide, I generally like Safer Brand fungicide or Daconil fungicide. Whatever fungicide you choose, make sure that it has Rose Black Spot listed on the label as one of the fungal diseases it treats.

Good garden hygiene, such as the removal of infected leaves, leaf litter and pruning off diseased stems (back to healthy wood) is also a very important part of treating any fungal disease, including Rose Black Spot.

Comment: Would it be ok to use fungicide in combination with another product? i.e., fertilizer, insecticide...

Comment: Yes. Using separate products together, like a fungicide and a fertilizer, is fine. It is just the 'all in one' products that usually don't quite live up to their claims.